# NiFi transfering data between processors

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to create a simple flow. Firstly, I need to take accountIds from REST service and then use received values to create new HTTP request to get token, and then use this token to create some requests with Oauth2.

[image: common_flow]

AccountIds flow:
[image: accountIds]

From `InvokeHttp` I'll receive some ids in json (REST written in Java and returns List with Integers). 99% chance that there will be only one number. My response looks like: `[40]`. Now I need to replace square brackets and get this number (using `SplitJson`). This number I should put to the next `getToken` as one of the GET param (on a screenshot i hardcode this):

[image: token]
[image]

This will return a token. Token is a `text/plain;charset=UTF-8`. And then, i want to use `InvokeHttp` again, add atribute `Authorization` and add to this attribute `Bearer + received token`. I do not really understand how to use the received data from processors in the following processors. Can someone explain how to reach it with my flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rest Api provides you with payload body - in nifi terms a `flowfile content`, you need to parse that incoming content using an `evaluatejson` (if payload is json - in most cases) and store it in `flow attributes`.
Then  this attributes will be used in the down stream processors.

Also to pass the `Authorization` to your InvokeHTTP you need to decalre it in the `InvokeHTTP` porcesor. The `${access_token}` is from the upstream attributes extraction.
[image]

Comment: I'm using `ExtractText` with `token = (.*)` attribute, but it returns flowfile with attributes: `token, token.0, token.1` with duplicates. Why? Received token is a plain text, not a json.